# jquery .next *?* issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

basically got this bit of code that doesn't work in ie8 & lower.

The automatic change fades out the current block of text, but doesnt fade in the new one which makes me think its the .next() that's playing up, as clicking the numbers (the .click function) works fine.

jQuery:

```
function doSlideshow() {
    if ($('.image_links a.selected').attr("rel") == "five") {
        the = $('.image_links a:first');
    } else {
        the = $('.image_links a.selected').next('a');
    }
    $('.image_links a.selected').removeClass("selected");
    $(the).addClass("selected");
    var theNum = $(the).attr("rel");
    $('.image_area .images img:not(.visible)').removeClass().addClass("reset");
    $('.image_area .images img#' + theNum).removeClass().addClass("que");
    $('.image_area .images img.visible').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('.image_area .images img.visible').removeClass().attr("style", "display:block;").addClass("reset");
        $('.image_area .images img.que').removeClass("que").addClass("visible")
    });
    $('.image_area .content .text').fadeOut();
    $('.image_area .content .text.' + theNum).fadeIn();
    thistimeout = setTimeout('doSlideshow()', 6000);
    return false;
}
$(function() {
    thistimeout = setTimeout('doSlideshow()', 6000);
    $('.image_area .images img').removeClass().addClass("reset");
    $('.image_area .images img#one').removeClass().addClass("visible");
    $('.image_links a').click(function() {
        clearTimeout(thistimeout);
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.image_links a.selected').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        var theNum = $(this).attr("rel");
        $('.image_area .content .text').fadeOut();
        $('.image_area .content .text.' + theNum).fadeIn();
        $('.image_area .images img:not(.visible)').removeClass().addClass("reset");
        $('.image_area .images img#' + theNum).removeClass().addClass("que");
        $('.image_area .images img.visible').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.image_area .images img.visible').removeClass().attr("style", "display:block;").addClass("reset");
            $('.image_area .images img.que').removeClass("que").addClass("visible")
        });
        thistimeout = setTimeout('doSlideshow()', 6000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the link:
http://b2j3new.zen-host.com
The affected area is the top image changer. Works fine in webkit/gecko

Mucho appreciato!

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Hi SLaks, I have took out the string and set it as just the function and still no luck.. thanks for feedback though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing (2 places)

```
thistimeout = setTimeout('doSlideshow()', 6000);
```

with:

```
thistimeout = setInterval(function() {doSlideshow();}, 6000);
```

Remove from doSlideshow:

```
thistimeout = setTimeout('doSlideshow()', 6000);
```

And change:

```
clearTimeout(thistimeout);
```

To:

```
clearInterval(thistimeout);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Jen, unfortunately that didn't work either. It looks like the function is working - as they both fadeOut, but then the next element doesnt fade in. Thanks for your ongoing help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IE 8 is not running you doSlideshow function at all.

This is a long shot, but you are missing a couple of semicolons in the javascript. I have seen IE sensitive to this kind of stuff before, but LIKE I SAID, it's a reach.

Fix the two lines that don't end in semicolons.

```
$('.image_area .images img.que').removeClass("que").addClass("visible")

$('.image_area .images img.que').removeClass("que").addClass("visible")
```

Comment: hi jen, thanks for the response. I gave that a go but to no avail. Quite strange!

Comment: Have you tried validating the markup? IE is also known to do weird things with js mixed with invalid markup.

Comment: Took my second attempt at an answer out. I didn't have all of your code in there when I tested. My bad.